# How can I loop the columns of a dataframe and then calling them as df.col without having python think col is a method?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops

I'm trying to loop all the columns of a dataframe but I can't call them inside the loop as df.col, apparently it reads col as a method and gives me an error because no such method exists.

```
for bin in bins:
    for col in app_train.columns:
        if app_train[col].isnull().any(): 
            app_train.loc[(app_train.col.isnull())&(app_train.YEARS_BINNED == bin),col] = app_train.col.mean()
        else: 
             continue
```

What I was trying to do was filtering the dataframe by bins, and then imputing the missing values using the mean of each column of the filtered dataframe.

This is what it tells me:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'

Comment: Don't use .notation shortcut instead use `app_train[col].isnull()` and `app_train[col].mean()`

Comment: If I understand your question you can use this oneliner : `df = df.fillna(df.groupby(['YEARS_BINNED']).transform('mean'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop are not needed since pandas can deal with this kind of operation:

```
df.fillna(df.groupby(['YEARS_BINNED']).transform('mean'),inplace=True)
```

This line will fill the NaN value of your dataframe with the mean of the respective column grouped by `YEARS_BINNED`

Answer (score 0):

Look at `app_train.col.isnull()` in your code.
In this case *col* means **literal** column name (and just this is
the cause of the error).

Change to `app_train[col].isnull()`. This time it is a reference to 
**variable** named *col*.